# oracle procedure looping a string and insert into another table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, procedure

I have this string : `RC1500ZQ10RC2400ZQ20RC23ZQ3RC2322ZQ22`

I need to create a **procedure or trigger** to split the above string and then insert it as a rows to another tables .

Like This :

```
RC = NEW ROW . 
ZQ = NEW COULMN .
Row 1 RC1500ZQ10 = 1500,10 
Row 2 RC2400ZQ20 = 2400,20
Row 3 RC23  ZQ3  = 23,3
Row 4 RC2322ZQ22 = 2322,22
```

and so on ..

Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any specific reason why you need procedure or Trigger for this?.

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with `CONNECT BY` in a single SQL. You may include the query in your procedure to perform `insert` by passing the string argument.

`'RC(.+?)ZQ'` - match anything between RC and next ZQ

`'ZQ(.+?)(RC|$)'` - match anything between ZQ and next RC or line end

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3121/9)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t as 
select 'RC1500ZQ10RC2400ZQ20RC23ZQ3RC2322ZQ22' as s from dual;
```

**Query 1**:

```
--INSERT INTO yourtarget(rc,zq) 
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(s, 'RC(.+?)ZQ', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1)     AS RC,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(s, 'ZQ(.+?)(RC|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) AS ZQ
FROM   t --or DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(s, 'RC(.+?)ZQ')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3121/9/0)**:

```
|   RC | ZQ |
|------|----|
| 1500 | 10 |
| 2400 | 20 |
|   23 |  3 |
| 2322 | 22 |
```